# Difficulty registering callback url with IBM watson speech-to-text npm module

Tags: express, npm, callback, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I'm trying to register a callback url for the IBM speechToText service, using express, and I keep getting a 400 response when I call speechToText.registerCallback.

I've already ensured that the url exists and is providing responses as expected via Postman. I also know that my SpeechToText service has correct credentials.

I'm not seeing the 'challenge_string' logged when I call the endpoint using registerCallback.

````
router.get('/callback', (req,res,next) => {
    console.log(req.query.challenge_string);
    return res.status(200);
});

router.post('/newStream', (req,res) => {

var speechToText = new SpeechToTextV1({
        username: <my_username>,
        password: <my_password>,
        url: 'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/'
      });

    const registerCallbackParams = {
        callback_url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/callback',
        user_secret: 'ThisIsMySecret',
    };

    speechToText.registerCallback(registerCallbackParams)
    .then(registerStatus => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(registerStatus, null, 2));
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(registerCallbackParams);
        console.log('error:', err);
    }); 

}```
````

Comment: Postman is good to start, but I would debug through the Network panel in Chrome to see which headers/body you're actually sending, and "preview" what the response details are. It's weird to pass an endpoint as a callback option, rather than them just giving you an audio stream source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the hostname in your callback url is `127.0.0.1`, that is not a public hostname, but the address of the loopback interface.

Comment: Thanks! I figured that out and then got stuck when I attached it to a Heroku app. apparently the way that Heroku deals with incoming requests to things at a <domain>.herokuapp.com is also incompatible with this request. I was able to fix it by setting up a custom domain. Thanks!